# Parameter 'href' should represent a valid URL

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-share

I'm using `next js` and using `react-share` for share a page. My problem is when I try to share a page then show me error like this:

`Parameter 'href' should represent a valid URL`

I don't know why.

I have tried like this way:

```
import {FacebookIcon, FacebookShareButton, FacebookShareCount} from 'react-share'

const shareUrl = global.window && window.location.href;


 <FacebookShareButton
        url={`${shareUrl}`}
        title={blog.title}
        className="Demo__some-network__share-button">
        <FacebookIcon
          size={32}
          round />
      </FacebookShareButton>
```

any suggestion please

Comment: Try using without `global.window &&`

Answer (score 2):

If you use the && operator and the condition is false, shareUrl value will be false and the url prop needs to be a string so you need to do something like this:

```
const shareUrl = window?.location.href ?? '';
```

In this case the window?. is telling js that if the window object is undefined or null you will return the empty string instead of false.

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you are developing on localhost (https://github.com/nygardk/react-share/issues/432)

Try to deploy it on a development server to test it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).